# CSS blur and retain sharp edges using absolute div

Tags: html, css

This works just fine if img is not set to absolute:

```
div img {
    filter: blur(5px);
        -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
        -moz-filter: blur(5px);
        -o-filter: blur(5px);
        -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    margin: -5px -10px -10px -5px;
}
div {
    margin: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Example working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/b8fLU/ (taken from another question)

But what if I want to do this with an absolute div using background-image?

```
<div id="background"></div>

#background {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    filter: blur(5px) brightness(0.75);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px) brightness(0.75);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px) brightness(0.75);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px) brightness(0.75);
    -o-filter: blur(5px) brightness(0.75);
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('images/bg.png');
    z-index: 1;
}
```

How can I achieve the same effect (blur but with sharp edges) using the setup above?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

put your blur element in a container like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="background"></div>
</div>
```

then instead of using `height:100%` and `width:100%` use like this:

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;          /* this is an example */
    height:300px;         /* this is an example */
    overflow:hidden;
}

#background {
    left:-15px;
    right:-15px;
    top:-15px;
    bottom:-15px;
    /* other styles */
}
```

you need to remove `15px` (or more/less) from each side of your element.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/b8fLU/249/) - [**Full DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/b8fLU/251/)

Comment: I need to use 100% width and height so that the background div fills the whole page

Comment: That image is still blurred around the edges

Comment: @jskidd3 look at new demo added

Comment: Note in Chrome this doesn't work if any of the parent elements have `position: relative` http://jsfiddle.net/tamlyn/b8fLU/401/

Answer (score 13):

An alternative to the answers I've been seeing for this, that I think is really clever, is using an svg to blur the `img`. It's described really well in this codepen https://codepen.io/johndjameson/full/xVjgPy/ so I'll just copy and paste that over here. Hopefully it'll be much more accessible on this thread.

To sum it up. You make an invisible svg element like this

```
 <svg class='hideSvgSoThatItSupportsFirefox'>
  <filter id='sharpBlur'>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='3'></feGaussianBlur>
    <feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 9 0'></feColorMatrix>
    <feComposite in2='SourceGraphic' operator='in'></feComposite>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

And then use CSS to blur by linking to the invisible svg element

```
.svgBlur { filter: url("#sharpBlur"); }
```

Finally you just add `svgBlur` to the `img` you want blurred

```
<img class='svgBlur' src='https://unsplash.it/360/240?image=511'>
```

And that's it! Worked really well for me.

```css
.cssBlur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  filter: blur(3px);
}

.svgBlur {
  -webkit-filter: url("#sharpBlur");
  filter: url("#sharpBlur");
}

.hideSvgSoThatItSupportsFirefox {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}

*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  padding: 40px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 840px;
}

svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
pre {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  line-height: 1.2;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

pre {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.emoji {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.grid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

.grid-box {
  padding-left: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .grid-box--1of2 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.mbf {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mbm {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.mbs {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .mbf_m {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .mbm_m {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class='hideSvgSoThatItSupportsFirefox'>
  <filter id='sharpBlur'>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='3'></feGaussianBlur>
    <feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 9 0'></feColorMatrix>
    <feComposite in2='SourceGraphic' operator='in'></feComposite>
  </filter>
</svg>
<h1>Blurred Image with Sharp Edges</h1>
<div class='grid mbm_m'>
  <div class='grid-box grid-box--1of2 mbs mbf_m'>
    <img class='mbf' src='https://unsplash.it/360/240?image=511'>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-box grid-box--1of2 mbm mbf_m'>
    <h2>Original image</h2>
    <p>
      Let’s blur this image in the browser. There are two types of filters we can use: CSS and SVG.
    </p>
    <p>If you want to keep the orginal’s sharp edges, you’re going to need SVG.</p>
    <p class='emoji mbf'></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='grid mbm'>
  <div class='grid-box grid-box--1of2 mbm mbf_m'>
    <img class='cssBlur mbs' src='https://unsplash.it/360/240?image=511'>
    <h2>Blurred with CSS</h2>
    <pre>filter: blur(3px)</pre>
    <p class='mbf'>
      The syntax in CSS is super simple, but this’ll fuzz up the edges around the image.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-box grid-box--1of2'>
    <img class='svgBlur mbs' src='https://unsplash.it/360/240?image=511'>
    <h2>Blurred with SVG</h2>
    <pre>filter: blur('#sharpBlur')</pre>
    <p class='mbf'>
      Here you reference a filter’s <code>id</code> from the SVG. See the difference? This one looks so clean!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed on mobile devices the blur sometimes will override the `overflow:hidden`. This can be fixed by adding a `border: 1px solid transparent;` to the container.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="absolute overflow-hidden min-w-full h-86">
    <img
      src={image.url}
      class="filter blur relative min-w-full h-90 object-cover transform scale-105" />
  </div>
```

`transform: scale(1.1)` on image inside of `overflow: hidden;` parent can do the trick